# htaccess mod rewrite in an aliased folder not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, alias

I have a site "new.mysite.com" in Drupal.
In the vhost file I have a directory "weight-loss" pointing to another location on the server for this website.
In that folder I have a mini-site based on Zend Framework which is using mod_rewrite.
The mod_rewrite is not working, and I'm thinking it's because this folder is an alias because the exact same mini-site works in another location without being in an aliased folder.
The mini-site in in "/home/weight-loss/admin/". The .htaccess file is "/home/weight-loss/admin/.htaccess"

http://new.mysite.com/weight-loss/admin/dashboard/index
should be :
http://new.mysite.com/weight-loss/admin/index.php?module=dashboard&controller=index

What am I doing wrong?

The vhost settings

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.100.142:80>
    ServerAdmin serveradmin@bbgi.com
    DocumentRoot /home/drupal_1
    ServerName new.mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite.com www.mysite.com
    Alias /weight-loss /home/weight-loss/
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mysite.com_err_log
      CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mysite.com_log special
    <Directory /home/drupal_1>
      Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
              AllowOverride All
              DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /weight-loss/admin/index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate the `<Directory /home/drupal_1>...</Directory>` and change the `/home/drupal_1` to `/home/weight-loss`. That should enable htaccess (and therefor also mod_rewrite)

Comment: Thank you very much Gerben. That was the answer!